# The input() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, translate

Hello i would like to know how to use input() that we use in python in javascript.
I wanted to translate this python code into javascript. But i'm stuck in the input() part.

```
def search_people():
search = input("Who do you want to search for: ") 
class people:
    def __init__(self, full_name, birthday, telnum, mail, adress, other):
        self.name = full_name
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.birthday = birthday #ddmmyyyy
        self.telnum = telnum
        self.mail = mail
        self.adress = adress
        self.other = other
```

So is there a way to use input() in javascript. I tried using the html tags but i couldn't really do it. And i would be also be happy if you can help me translate thi pythone code to javascript. But mainly Can you guys help me fin how to do it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt  <-- everything you need to know

Comment: In order to help you I need to know what does "input()" do in Python.

Comment: @floverdevel It basically let's you input text into a variable like this: letter = input("Input a letter ") that let's you input a letter into the variable letter. I want it to work in a way that i can do this: if letter equals to "something" do this.

Comment: Your JavaScript will run in a browser or on a server (like node.js)?

Answer (score 2):

Python and JavaScript are fundamentally different in this respect. JS relies on elements that are inside of your DOM (web page) but JS won't know about them until you set up the "binding" between them. The easiest way to do what you want without worrying about all that would be:

```
var input = window.prompt('What is your search term?');
alert(input);
```

If you would like to display the results on the webpage without an alert, create an HTML element to hold the value (in your HTML of course), and set the text of the element to it in your javascript:

```
<span id="myResults"></span>
document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML=input;
```

Here is how the entire page would be set up:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The Web site</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The Web site">
    <meta name="author" content="The Web site">

    <!-- any external CSS would get linked like this -->  
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0"> -->

    <!-- this is for some Internet Explorer backwards compatibility [if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <span id="myResults"></span>


    <!--    this is how you would link external javascript files -->  
    <!-- <script src="js/scripts.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var input = window.prompt('What is your search term?');
        document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML=input;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it directly on the webpage without the alert. Like the web page displays a box or something of that sort. And the user can input something. And then i should be able to use something like if, else if statements.

Comment: edited to reflect request. be sure to mark as answer if it helped out!

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: how are you linking your js to your HTML? are you sure you are doing it correctly? Easiest way to do this is to save your file as an HTML file, and add <script> tags to the bottom of your HTML. That is certainly the issue, the code itself works, you can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I did that but it gave me a blank page

Comment: I have edited answer with complete HTML page. This should work literally as copy and paste. Please mark as answer if it helped.